# Windows XP: saving large files on network share stalls

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares

When I transfer larger files (a few hundred MB) on a network share (either Buffalo LinkStation or other Windows machine) from my Windows XP Pro SP3, it always stalls. Smaller files are no problem, reading from a network share is also no problem. I already had this problem on my notebook and now on my desktop machine, so I assume that it most likely is no driver problem.

Does anybody have a clue what could be the problem — or better: the solution?

Comment: Are the network shares all on the same machine or is it various machines?

Comment: Can you look at remote file's logs? Is remote on your LAN or internet?  Does transfer start and then stall at same point on same file every time?  Does it stall after same amount of transfer regardless of which file you're working with?

Answers to the above may help if you are having trouble with the remote system instead of yours.  Possibly read errors on remote, full file system, buffer issues with remote or poorly managed locks on remote ? Since it's same problem on 2 machines I'm thinking the other guy is where problem can be found...

Comment: I had this problem with two "servers" (Buffalo LinkStation and other Windows machine) and with two "clients" (two different machines with XP installation).

Comment: For one file it stalls after 154MB (47%), for another after 199MB (19%).

Comment: I'm with hotei on this one: it would be very helpful to see the remote computer's event logs. I'm thinking you'll see **Delayed Write Failed** errors.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using RoboCopy solves this; or rather, it prevents the problem.  RoboCopy is also free.  There is a GUI/frontend for it as well, but I prefer the CLI.